# Sybase Unwired Platform (SUP) Authentication with SAP

Tags: authentication, sup

I have few queries in authenticating SUP user against SAP. Please assume that we don’t have SSO in our SAP landscape.
a)  I use Basic HTTP authentication to authenticate the user against the SAP System. I use the URL http://SAPSERVER.DEV.COM:8000/sap/bc/ping?sap-client=200 . Is this a right approach to authenticate the user.
b)  If my WF application is an Server initiated then whenever a  DCN updates SUP in that case how the authentication happens? Should we have to challenge credentials again or can we reuse the values provided by user during application initial login.
c)  If I authenticate with method (a) and if there is an passcode change or user termination at the SAP side will that be intimated to application?
Thanks
-Arun